Illegal use of lambda expression inside of requires-clause?
Why do all 3 compilers reject the call to f2? Do we break any rules of the C++20 standard when invoking an immediately invoked lambda expression instead of a function inside a requires-clause?
// note: the function body of `g` is the exact same as the
//   lambda body of the requires-clause of function `f2`

constexpr auto g(auto b) {
    using c1 = decltype([](int){ return true; });
    using c2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; });
    struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); };
    return v{}(decltype(b){});
}
auto f1(auto a) requires (g(decltype(a){})) {}
auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b) {
    using c1 = decltype([](int){ return true; });
    using c2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; });
    struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); };
    return v{}(decltype(b){});
}(decltype(a){})) {}

auto m() {
    f1(true); // all ok
    f2(true); // all reject
}

Demo

Clang's error message:
<source>:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f2'
   12 |     f2(true);
      |     ^~
<source>:9:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied
[with a:auto = bool]
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |      ^
<source>:9:27: note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed:
no matching function
for call to object of type '(lambda at <source>:9:27)'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                           ^

GCC's error message:
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct<lambda(auto:4)>::v':
<source>:9:39:   required from '<lambda(auto:4)> [with auto:4 = bool]'
    4 |     struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); }; \
      |                                                               ^
<source>:9:45:   required by substitution of 'template<class auto:3> auto
f2(auto:3) requires (<lambda>)({}) [with auto:3 = bool]'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:7:   required from here
   12 |     f2(true);
      |     ~~^~~~~~
<source>:4:44: error: type '<lambda(auto:4)>::v::<lambda(int)>' is not a base
type for type '<lambda(auto:4)>::v'
    4 |     struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); }; \
      |                                            ^
<source>:9:39: note: in expansion of macro 'body'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                                       ^~~~
<source>:4:60: error: type '<lambda(auto:4)>::v::<lambda(bool)>' is not a base
type for type '<lambda(auto:4)>::v'
    4 |     struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); }; \
      |                                                            ^
<source>:9:39: note: in expansion of macro 'body'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                                       ^~~~
<source>: In instantiation of '<lambda(auto:4)> [with auto:4 = bool]':
<source>:9:45:   required by substitution of 'template<class auto:3> auto
f2(auto:3) requires (<lambda>)({}) [with auto:3 = bool]'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:7:   required from here
   12 |     f2(true);
      |     ~~^~~~~~
<source>:5:15: error: request for member 'operator()' is ambiguous
    5 |     return v{}(decltype(b){});
      |            ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:39: note: in expansion of macro 'body'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                                       ^~~~
<source>:3:25: note: candidates are: '<lambda(auto:4)>::<lambda(bool)>'
    3 |     using c2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; }); \
      |                         ^
<source>:9:39: note: in expansion of macro 'body'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                                       ^~~~
<source>:2:25: note:                 '<lambda(auto:4)>::<lambda(int)>'
    2 |     using c1 = decltype([](int){ return true; }); \
      |                         ^
<source>:9:39: note: in expansion of macro 'body'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |                                       ^~~~
<source>: In function 'auto m()':
<source>:12:7: error: no matching function for call to 'f2(bool)'
   12 |     f2(true);
      |     ~~^~~~~~
<source>:9:6: note: candidate: 'template<class auto:3> auto f2(auto:3)
requires (<lambda>)({})'
    9 | auto f2(auto a) requires ([](auto b){ body }(decltype(a){})){}
      |      ^~
<source>:9:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted
in errors seen above


IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is, to my knowledge, a JS term, it's weird to use it without explanation in a completely different language (one where the terminology is so different that "function expression" doesn't even exist as a language term).

There's a lot going on in your code. If you want to know if a call to a lambda expression is valid in a requires clause, why not test against the simplest possible lambda expression instead of this horrible mess? Demo.

@ShadowRanger IIFEs or IILEs, it's like tomato tomato. It's definitely a term that's being used more often in modern C++, see also (from 2016): IIFE for complex initialization.

Are you simply trying to make a requires clause to check that the argument is int or bool? I'm sure there's a simpler way

@n.m.couldbeanAI You're right. That's not really what I want to test so I changed the title accordingly.

@alter_igel This is a simplification of a more complete piece of code. I'm not asking how to do this differently, I'm asking if what is happening here is compliant with the C++20 standard.

We are dealing with several unrelated compiler bugs.
The ICE of MSVC is just that: a compiler bug, by definition. We cannot even begin to guess whether it is related to some or another part of the standard. So we cannot exclude MSVC from further discussion.
Let's simplify a bit:
#define body \
    struct v { constexpr bool operator()(bool) {return true;}}; \
    return v{}(true);

auto f2(auto a) requires ([](bool b){ body }(true)){}
auto m() {
    f2(true);
}

Now clang has an ICE, which allows us to exclude it from consideration.
So two compilers out of three are definitely buggy in this area, and only gcc is not proven guilty yet. But further experimentation only makes it more suspicious. For example, replacing the definition of c1 and c2 with
using cc1 = decltype([](int){ return true; }); struct c1 : cc1{}; \
using cc2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; }); struct c2 : cc2{}; \

makes gcc accept the code, which makes a total of zero sense. The two other compilers still fail the same way as before.
Let's try to reduce the number of unknowns further.
auto f2(auto a) { 
    auto z = [](auto b) {
        using c1 = decltype([](int){ return true; });
        using c2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; });
        struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); };
        return v{}(decltype(b){});
    };
    return z(decltype(a){});
}

int main()
{
    f2(true);
}

No requires clause! gcc rejects this with the same error as before. But:
auto f2(auto a) { 
     auto z = [](auto b) {
         using cc1 = decltype([](int){ return true; });
         struct c1 : cc1 {};
         using cc2 = decltype([](bool){ return true; }); 
         struct c2 : cc2 {};
         struct v : c1, c2 { using c1::operator(), c2::operator(); };
         return v{}(decltype(b){});
     };
     return z(decltype(a){});
}

int main()
{
    f2(true);
}

Add a level of indirection, and gcc is OK with it.
Conclusion: all three compilers are buggy, and this doesn't necessarily has to do with the requires clause.

Would you include the behaviour of not being allowed to use the current class type in its constexpr / metaprogramming member functions because the class is "not yet completely defined or rather it didn't finish the complete definition and parsing" and result in compile error? Or would you rate it separate? I am still not convinced that is the way it should be on the long run (maybe it will be fixed with some sort of "delayed re-parsing" or some sort of magical internal forward declaration but I don't remember it being included in proposals). Unless that issue is unrelated to the OP's.

@TheNomad I don't see anything that points to the current class name here. I see inability of gcc to recognize the type of a lambda as a direct base class of another class in some circumstances, while a non-lambda type is OK in the same context.

I know, I said they are not related, I was asking your opinion on the behavior of that issue, meaning, if you relate it to this or consider it separate. To me they seemed slightly (or very slightly) related, but couldn't really say I considered them similar enough for sure. But since you're more experienced, I was wondering about your opinion.

@TheNomad I don't see how these things are related but I'm not an auuthority.
